# Allowing only Youtube/Vimeo iframes in markdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, youtube, xss, markdown

I'm trying to allow users to embed youtube or vimeo videos in posts for a Rails3 app we're working on, and both use iframes now. The sanitize helper seems like it only allows you to whitelist tags on a global basis - further, youtube has a consistent class for their iframes, but vimeo does not.

How would you go about whitelisting embeds from those two urls, but not allow them otherwise?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? If so, I'm interested.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about how to whitelist tags using the sanitize method, but you could always filter through another method and specifically check for the src using regex and only write out if it matched youtube.

```
def santize_iframe(text)
  text.gsub(/\<iframe( src="(.+?)")?\>(.+?)\<\/iframe\>/m) do
    if $2.include? "youtube.com"
        ... logic to display video
    else
        ""
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

http://github.com/rgrove/sanitize/

This is a great project, with an example for youtube embeds allowing as well.  Youtube has recently changed to iframe, and I'm submitting an example "filter for it" to them:

```
T_YOUTUBE_IFRAME = lambda do |env|
 node      = env[:node]
 return nil unless (env[:node_name] == 'iframe')

 if node['src'] =~ /^http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\//
   node['src'] += "?test" 

   return {:node_whitelist => [node]}
 end
end
```